# Requiring a grammatical explanation for the following sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

[The source](https://quizlet.com/134775748/words-for-april-25-27-29-2-4-6-flash-cards/)

> Often we think that great leaders are those who are gregarious, always in the middle of a large group of people; **yet**, as Mahatma Gandhi and many others have shown us, leaders can also be introverted.

Shouldn’t the conjunction “yet” be placed before leaders to show the contrast?

> Often we think that great leaders are those who are gregarious, always in the middle of a large group of people, as Mahatma Gandhi and many others have shown us; **yet** leaders can also be introverted.

---

**Edited**

Good observation taken from comments, by @joiedevivre

- The parenthetical prepositional phrase can be moved around within the clause, but it can't go before yet. Yet must head this clause.

Comment: I have no idea whether Gandhi was gregarious or introverted, but without a doubt, your cited writer ***believes he was introverted***. And noting the *very* careful use of a semicolon, I'm inclined to think he's probably right. Gandhi probably only looks "gregarious" to some because of the way he has to be portrayed in films.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a non-issue based on different opinions of Gandhi's temperament

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question asks nothing about Ghandi's temperament. It asks about the heading to a clause indicating disagreement with a preceding clause. It is a question about the English language. I am voting to leave it open.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: The text as cited is perfectly formed, and has a very clear meaning. OP's "suggested correction" is clumsy phrasing that means pretty much the exact opposite, for which the only *possible* reason I can see is that OP thinks Gandhi was "gregarious" rather than "introverted", so he's rewritten the text so it says that. And so far as I'm concerned, both the current answers are hopelessly misleading (one simply promotes OP's erroneous assessment, the other mistakenly claims the text is ambiguous).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I fully agree that the source is perfectly clear and correct. But I do not think that your reading of the OP's revision is necessarily an attempt to contradict the source. I read it as asking whether "yet" had to precede the main thought. The sentence is primarily about leaders. The subordinate clause about Ghandi is mere supporting evidence. The question can read as a purely grammatical one. I don't think we should close a question that can be construed as linguistic because it can be construed otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that one answer is awful because the first sentence is not at all ambiguous. But we shouldn't close a question because it elicits a bad answer.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: Use of the semicolon may be falling off, but its *significance* hasn't changed, and is easily looked up. But if it *is* a "valid" question, it's probably a duplicate of [Use of “yet”, “however” and “but”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113224/) or others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You seem to think that I find the first sentence, the one from the source, ambiguous or flawed. I do not. I agree with you about the semicolon. I simply read the OP as asking about the proper placement of "yet."

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: It never occurred to me that *you* might not understand the original text. My disagreement is that you seem to think OP's *misunderstanding* somehow relates to the actual syntax (which might justify exploring what's going on), but so far as I'm concerned it's a completely untenable interpretation based *solely* on OP's prior misconception as regards whether Gandhi was introverted or gregarious. That's to say it's about disagreement over "facts", not really about language use at all.

Comment: My point of the question could simply lie in whether “parenthetical information, as Mahatma Ganhidi...” attributes to great leaders who are gregarious or not” @FumbleFingers

Comment: Bavyan - in virtually any context I can think of (and *definitely* in your example), a semicolon can validly be replaced by a full stop. ***Yet** as your rewrite clearly shows, you don't recognise that.* Of course, I can also write *As your rewrite clearly shows, you don't recognise that **yet**,* but that would mean something completely different.

Comment: Could you just, please, reconstruct to make it clear! @FumbleFingers  just move the phrase to a simple way.

Comment: Statement 1: *Great leaders are [usually thought of as] gregarious*. Statement 2: *Leaders can also be introverted*. Because #2 somewhat "contradicts" #1, it's reasonable to introduce it with a conjunction such as ***yet, but, nevertheless, however***. Those first two conjunctions (unlike the last two) *can't* be put at the end of a statement, so #2 can't be rephrased to ***Leaders can also be introverted but***. In principle, ***yet*** can be used at the end of a statement, but only when it means ***up until the present time***, not when it means ***but***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what you might have initially thought, the conjunction *yet* does go before *leaders*. Just move that "parenthetical" clause beginning with *as*, which is set off by a pair of commas, out of the way to the end of the sentence and you will see that the sentence reads just as well:

> Often we think that great leaders are those who are gregarious, always in the middle of a large group of people; **yet** leaders can also be introverted **as Mahatma Gandhi and many others have shown us**.

Or, as you suggested, you can place it after *leaders* while, very importantly, not forgetting to surround it with a pair of commas. The sentence, as you can see, still reads just as good as the original one:

> Often we think that great leaders are those who are gregarious, always in the middle of a large group of people; **yet** leaders, **as Mahatma Gandhi and many others have shown us**, can also be introverted.

As a couple of people in the comments section aptly pointed out, in order to be grammatically correct, sentences of this type should always have their second clauses begin with *yet*. In other words, the beginning of the second clause is the only place where *yet* can go in a sentence of this type.

Comment: Or could be constructed this way. Yet leaders, as mahatgandy and..., can also be introverted.  ?

Comment: Just as a minor addition, I think it might be useful to point out that the OPs rewrite doesn't makes sense. The parenthetical prepositional phrase can be moved around within the clause, but it *can't* go before *yet.* *Yet* must head this clause.

Comment: @joiedevivre, Thank you for your comment. That's a good observation.

Comment: I have read this answer several times. It is a correct answer. I have up voted it. And yet the topic sentence strikes me as not quite right. "'Yet' must head the clause" is the key thought as J has said. Then you can say. "Putting "yet" as the head ensures that it precedes "leaders." It is not necessary that "yet" immediately precede "leaders."

Comment: @Jeff Morrow Thank you for your time. But what exactly do you find wrong about this sentence?

Comment: My comment accidentally got published before I was through.

Comment: I forgot to ask you why semicolon is used instead of comma, as i know , coordinating conjunction are preceded by comma not semicolon @CookieMonster

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo As I told you in the answer it's not a conjunction. It's an adverb. (I'm pretty sure it's an adverb.)

Comment: In this example, **Yet** gives the meaning of “but”, I had just looked into a link, it shows that “but” could be interchangeable to “yet” only when they are conjunctions not as adverbs. http://grammarist.com/usage/but-and-yet/ @CookieMonster

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo Oh, yeah, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking. It's definitely used as a conjugation in your example. It even says that in my dictionary where I was looking it up. I for some reason thought that it said "adverb" instead of "conjunction". Anyhow. I don't know why they used a semicolon there. But one thing that's for certain is that the basic pattern for "yet" when it's used as a conjunction is **"something something, yet something else is true"**. It always goes at the beginning of the second clause just like **but** does.

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo The **something something** in your example is all the stuff that precedes that semicolon we talked about.

Comment: @CookieMonster, I got it, there is a rule that when we use or separate items with commas (more than one comma), we probably insert semicolon instead of comma, so we don’t fall in confusion. Look at the rule **3** of using semicolon.

Comment: https://www.une.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/11771/WC_Punctuating-with-semicolons-and-colons.pdf

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo That''s a good find!

Answer (score -2):

These sentences are ambiguous. Without knowing anything much about Gandhi, I as the reader cannot tell whether we are being told that he is an exemplar of an introverted leader, contrary to the expectation stated in the first clause, or whether what he taught, being an extravert himself, that we should not think that leaders must always be extraverts.
As ever, what you write must be determined by the thought that you wish to convey. If that thought is "Hey, leaders can be introverts!" then put Gandhi and the rest at the end of the sentence (and make clear what they are evidence of). If that thought is "the example of Gandhi contrasts with our prejudice that leaders must extraverts", then bring Gandhi up immediately after the "yet" and also make clear why Gandhi is there (is he the example of the introvert, or the teacher who told us about introverted leaders).